# Updating DataGrid on button click in another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two windows: (1) `Home` and (2) `Add`
What I want to do is to update the `DataGrid` on `Home` whenever I hit the `Submit` button on the `Add` page.

The data loaded in the `DataGrid` is a `CSV File`. I'm hoping to accomplish this without the use of `MVVM` if that is possible.

So far, the code that I have works but only on the first run. For example, I fill up the fields in `Add` then hit the `Submit` button for the first time. The `DataGrid` would update but when I try it for a second time (without closing the application), it would no longer do what I want it to do. How can I resolve this?

`Submit` button click event in `Add`

```
 public void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        save();
        string edata = @"Employees.txt";
        Home h = new Home();
        h.grid.ItemsSource = edata.ToList();
        btn_clear_Click(sender, e);
        error_mssg.Text = "** SUCCESS! **";            
    }
```

`Home` page xaml

```
<StackPanel Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

`Home` page cs

```
public void Populate()
{       
    DataTable table = LoadDataGrid.display(@"EmployeeData.txt");
    grid.DataContext = table;
}
```

`LoadDataGrid` cs

```
public static DataTable display(string path)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

    }
    return dt;
}
```

I also added the code I used to populate the DataGrid with the contents of the csv file in case it is needed.

I also tried doing

```
h.grid.Items.Refresh();
```

instead of

```
h.grid.ItemsSource = edata.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
public class Home {
     private AddPage ap;

     public void createAddPage() {
         ap = new AddPage();
         ap.setHome(this);
     }

    public DataGrid getDataGrid() {
        return your_datagrid;
    }
}

public class AddPage {
    private Home home;

    public void setHome(Home home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

   public void button_click(/*some params*/) {
       DataGrid dg = home.getDataGrid();
       //do stuff with dg...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created a simple solution that i think solves your problem. I simplified it to a case where your "Home" window displays a list of names. In the second window, a user can type in a new name that is then added to the list of names displayed in the first window.
Approach: 
The solution was to add an event to the second window. When the "Home" window creates an instance of the second window, the home window subscribes to the second window's event. When the second window fires the event, the second window passes the new name to be added to the list displayed on the first window.
So, adding to the list is done in the "Home" window.
Note: The list of items being displayed is actually an `ObservableCollection<string>`.
Here are the two windows:
[image: Windows]

Here's the custom EventArgs object that i use to pass the details of the event, in this case, the new name just-added in the second window:

```
public class NameAddedEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code in my "Home" window. The window is simply name "MainWindow":

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window1 = new Window1();
        window1.ItemAddedEvent += ItemAddedEventHandler;
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void ItemAddedEventHandler(object sender, NameAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as ObservableCollection<string>).Add(e.NewName);
    }
}
```

So as you can see, when i create "Window1", which is the second window, i subscribe to its event.
Here's the code in Window1:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public event EventHandler<NameAddedEventArgs> ItemAddedEvent;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseNewNameEvent(txtInput.Text);
    }

    protected void RaiseNewNameEvent(string newName)
    {
        var nameAddedEventArgs = new NameAddedEventArgs { NewName=newName };
        var handler = ItemAddedEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, nameAddedEventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when the button is clicked to add the name (the name is typed into txtInput), i raise the event, passing in the new name typed-in.